# Swift MQTT libmosquitto cleanSession set to false yet unable to set up a persistent subscription

Tags: swift, mqtt, libmosquitto

```
client = MosquittoClient(clientId: "client1")
client?.delegate = self
client?.port = 1883
client?.host = "someIPAddress"
client!.cleanSession = false
client?.connect()
```

libmosquitto is a objective c library that is bridged over into a swift project. So after setting the cleanSession to false, i am still unable to set up a persistent subscription or receive message when offline.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: There is no error. However, when i push a message to the client when it is offline, it is expected for the client to get the message once it is reconnected. But that is not the case. @pableiros

Comment: Which broker are you using?

Comment: IBM WebSphere @hardillb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a cleanSession = false will not do your job.. If you want to receive a message after reconnection it will require QOS..

By default qos of message and subscribe is 0 which will not guarantee that message will be delivered to the offline clients..

You need to do 2 things:
1. When you subscribe for a topic subscribe it with QOS 1 or 2.
2. When you publish a message that you want to be delivered to offline clients send with qos 1 or 2.

Nd also use same client IDs for connecting.. If you want that the messages also be received by new clients that use retain=true while publishing message

Comment: I am already subscribed to a topic with QOS 1 and also published message to offline clients with QOS 1 as well. However, the client are still unable to receive any message when offline.

Comment: Using same client id while connecting to broker?

Comment: Yeah. Definitely the same